# React and reactstrap table with action buttons

Tags: javascript, html-table, reactjs, reactstrap

I am new to react and am creating a table with react and reactstrap. Was trying to find a reference for building a table that has some functionality for each row within the table. Not having much luck.

My initial code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Media,
  Button,
} from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const UserPreview = ({user}) => (
  <tr className="user">
    <td>
      <Media>
        <img
          alt={`${user.name} avatar`}
          className="avatar d-flex mr-3"
          src={user.url} />
        <Media body>{user.name}</Media>
      </Media>
    </td>
    <td>admin</td>
    <td className='flex justify-between'>
      <Button>Update</Button>
      <Button>Delete</Button>
      <Button>Cancel</Button>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

UserPreview.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    // TODO: add an url proptype.
    url: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default UserPreview;
```

Hoping some of you can point me to some locations where I could find a working table that has an edit, delete, etc... functionality for each row within the table.